# Can I filter 2 different CommandType using Poweshell?

Tags: powershell

Here is my roadblock, I am creating a filter that will check for wildcards but from 2 different CommandType

Here is my sample filter
`($_.PSParentPath -notlike $Exclusion1) -and ($_.Issuer -notlike $Exclusion2)`

I want to filter a word from $*.PSParentPath and from $*.Issuer. Is this possible? IF it is can someone give me some pointers?

Thank you in advance

```
$Expiry = Get-ChildItem -Path cert: -Recurse
$ExpiryDetails1 = $Expiry | Where-object { 
    $_.notafter -le (get-date).Adddays($DaysBeforeExpiry) -AND
    $_.notafter -gt (get-date) -AND 
    ($_.PSParentPath -notlike $Exclusion1) -AND
    ($_.PSParentPath -notlike $Exclusion2) -AND 
    ($_.PSParentPath -notlike $Exclusion3) -AND 
    ($_.Issuer -notlike $Exclusion4) -AND 
    ($_.Issuer -notlike $Exclusion5)
} | 
Select-Object psparentpath, issuer, subject, notafter | 
format-list
```

Comment: Yes lol definitely possible. Can you share the rest of your code? To include what your populating in those variables

Comment: Hi Abraham, thank you for saying that! here is the rest of my script. Its a SSL Certificate Expiry  ```$Expiry = Get-ChildItem -Path cert: -Recurse 

$ExpiryDetails1 = $Expiry | Where-object { $_.notafter -le (get-date).Adddays($DaysBeforeExpiry)  -AND $_.notafter -gt (get-date)  -AND ($_.PSParentPath -notlike $Exclusion1) -AND ($_.PSParentPath -notlike $Exclusion2) -AND ($_.PSParentPath -notlike $Exclusion3) -AND ($_.Issuer -notlike $Exclusion4) -AND ($_.Issuer -notlike $Exclusion5)} | Select-Object psparentpath, issuer, subject, notafter | format-list```

Comment: Don't forget that like and notlike use wildcards *

Answer (score 1):

So one of the things we can do is expand away from `-Like` and `-NotLike`

And use `-Match` and `-NotMatch`, this uses Regex to determine if something is `$True`

Example 1
Lets create a List of Words and Filters then get the results

```
$Words = "Apple", "Bananas","Cherry","Dog","Phone","Pager","Log"

$Filters = ("A*", "*R*").Replace("\","\\").Replace(".","\.").Replace("*",".") -join "|"

$Words | ?{@($_) -notmatch $Filters}
```

Results

```
Dog
Phone
Log
```

The magic is turning the `-Like` and `-NotLike` statement into a Regex one

First in Regex we need escape out characters that have power, The First one is the `\` backslash, the `\` is the escape char for regex.

Next is the `.` which is the wildcard for regex so we will `\` escape it.

Lastly we will replace `*` to `.` and instead of passing a array of `[string[]]` we will make a singular sting using regex version of `-and` which is `|`.

**There are more things that will need to be escaped from regex if you do more advanced searches

So we take an array of filters and turn it into regex
In this example we take `A*` and `*R*`

```
$Filters = ("A*", "*R*").Replace("\","\\").Replace(".","\.").Replace("*",".") -join "|"
```

This makes `$Filters` look like

```
A.|.R.
```

So lets make a more advanced case and create Objects and Filter by Fields

Example 2
Make 1001 custom objects with 2 properties `Item1` and `Item2` that are randomly filled from `$words` and only returns the items that do not have `*A*` or `*R*` in them

```
$Words = "Apple", "Bananas","Cherry","Dog","Phone","Pager","Log"

$Filters = ("A*", "*R*").Replace("\","\\").Replace(".","\.").Replace("*",".") -join "|"

$Items = 0..1000  | %{
    New-Object PSObject -Property @{
        Item1 = $Words[(Get-Random -Minimum 0 -Maximum $Words.Count)]
        Item2 = $Words[(Get-Random -Minimum 0 -Maximum $Words.Count)]
    }
}

$Items | ?{$_.Item1 -notmatch $Filters -and $_.Item2 -notmatch $Filters}
```

That returns

```
Item1 Item2
----- -----
Phone Phone
Dog   Dog
Log   Phone
Dog   Phone
Log   Dog
Log   Phone
...   ...
```

Hopefully this helps :)

Have a Great Day!

So Edit Here because you posted your code

Seems what you need is this

```
$IssuerExclusions = ("*MS-Organization-P2P-Access*", "*Windows Azure CRP Certificate Generator*", "*GlobalSign*").Replace("\","\\").Replace(".","\.").Replace("*",".") -join "|"

$PathExclusions = ("C:\*","D:\*").Replace("\","\\").Replace(".","\.").Replace("*",".") -join "|"

$Expiry = Get-ChildItem -Path cert: -Recurse

$Date = Get-Date

$ExpiryDetails = $Expiry | Where-object { 
    $_.notafter -le $Date.AddDays($DaysBeforeExpiry) -AND
    $_.notafter -gt $Date -AND 
    $_.PSParentPath -notmatch $PathExclusions -AND
    $_.Issuer -notmatch $IssuerExclusions
} | 
Select-Object psparentpath, issuer, subject, notafter | 
format-list
```

Comment: $PathExclusions works but when I added the the wildcards for $IssuerExclusion, It did not filter it out. Here is the value I entered `$IssuerExclusions = "*MS-Organization-P2P-Access*", "*Windows Azure CRP Certificate Generator*", "*GlobalSign*"`. It still shows the GlobalSign at least . Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: So if you are checking aginst multable wildcards you should use the -match stuff 
`$PathExclusions = ("C:\*","D:\*").Replace("\","\\").Replace(".","\.").Replace("*",".") -join "|"`. I updated the script

Comment: If this was helpful please mark this answer as correct